# ANTLR MismatchedTokenException on simple grammar

Tags: antlr

I'm completely new to ANTLR and EBNF grammars to begin with, so this is probably a basic issue I'm simply not understanding.

I have a rule such as:

```
version_line : WS? 'VERS' WS? '=' WS? '1.0' WS? EOL ;
WS : ' '+ ;
EOL : '\r' | '\n' | '\r\n' | '\n\r' ;
```

that matches a statement in my input file that looks like this (with optional whitespace):

```
VERSION = 1.0
```

With the rule form above, I'm getting a successful match, although I get an exception with this form:

```
version_line : WS? 'VERS' WS? '=' WS? '1' '.0' WS? EOL ;
```

or this form:

```
version_line : WS? 'VERS' WS? '=' WS? DIGIT '.0' WS? EOL ;
DIGIT : '1' ;
```

Why is this different? I discovered this issue when trying to decompose the rule even more, hopefully ending up with something like this:

```
version_line : WS? 'VERS' WS? '=' WS? DIGIT '.' DIGIT WS? EOL ;
DIGIT : '0'..'9' ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no problem, all four grammars produce the expected AST:

### 1

```
version_line : WS? 'VERSION' WS? '=' WS? '1.0' WS? EOL ;
WS : ' '+ ;
EOL : '\r' | '\n' | '\r\n' | '\n\r' ;
```

[image]

### 2

```
version_line : WS? 'VERSION' WS? '=' WS? '1' '.0' WS? EOL ;
WS : ' '+ ;
EOL : '\r' | '\n' | '\r\n' | '\n\r' ;
```

[image]

### 3

```
version_line : WS? 'VERSION' WS? '=' WS? DIGIT '.0' WS? EOL ;
DIGIT : '1' ;
WS : ' '+ ;
EOL : '\r' | '\n' | '\r\n' | '\n\r' ;
```

[image]

### 4

```
version_line : WS? 'VERSION' WS? '=' WS? DIGIT '.' DIGIT WS? EOL ;
DIGIT : '0'..'9' ;
WS : ' '+ ;
EOL : '\r' | '\n' | '\r\n' | '\n\r' ;
```

[image]

with input:

```
VERSION = 1.0
#
```

(Note that the `#` in the input is a new line char!)

Tested with [ANTLRWorks](https://web.archive.org/web/20121221164145/http://www.antlr.org:80/works/index.html) v1.3.1.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. This must be a problem with conflicts elsewhere in the file. You gave me a good idea for how to debug it, though (start from one rule and slowly expand).

Comment: @jjkparker, yes, that's the way I do it as well: write some rules, test it. Write some more rules, test it, etc.